# Android Startmanaging cursor

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make a datagridview from sqlite db

i found below code in online

```
private void populateGrid()
{

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Cursor c = dbHelper.fetchAllScores();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] cols = new String[] { TodoDbAdapter.KEY_PLAYDATE, TodoDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALA, TodoDbAdapter.KEY_NUMVALB};
    int[]   views = new int[] { R.id.txt_date, R.id.txt_no, R.id.txt_yes};

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.listviewtemp, c, cols, views);

    Log.w("NumRows",adapter.getCount() + "");

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

But i geeting not found method in **startManagingCursor(cursor);** what i have to right in that method, or i forget to import something? plz help

Comment: Use `getActivity().startManagingCursor(c);` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

startManagingCursor(c);

You need to tell it to manage the cursor you created.

Comment: but eclipse saying there is no such method